# ArrayList not adding String

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to get a word count of a string entered by a user but I keep getting "0" back as a result. I can't figure out what to do.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> A=new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.print("Enter a sentence: ");
    String a=reader.next();

    int charCount=a.length();
    int space;
    int period;
    int wordCount=0;
    //word count\

    for (int i=0; i<1; i++){
        space=a.indexOf(" ");
        if (a.charAt(0)!=' '){
            if (space!=-1){
                A.add(i, a.substring(0, space-1));
                a=a.substring(a.indexOf(" ")+1, charCount-1);
            }
            if (space==-1&&a.charAt(charCount-1)=='.'){
                period=a.indexOf(".");
                A.add(i, a.substring(0, period));
            }
            charCount=a.length();
        }
        wordCount=A.size();
    }
    System.out.print("Word Count: "+A.size());  
}
```

Comment: `reader.next()` only gets a single word.  Try `reader.nextLine()`.

Comment: And besides, can't you just use `sentence.trim().split(" ").length`? (I renamed `a` to `sentence` because it makes more sense)

Comment: Alternately, you can use `reader.next()` to repeatedly read words and count them and get rid of your `indexOf(" ")`.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try like this-

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner reader=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");

    String str1 = reader.nextLine();

    String[] wordArray = str1.trim().split("\\s+");
    int wordCount = wordArray.length;

    System.out.println("Word count is = " + wordCount);
}
```